# Refreshing part of a page in a React SPA

Tags: reactjs, render

I have a React app which initially renders as so

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <GlobalNav />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact Component={Home} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact Component={Contact} />        
      </Routes>
    <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

/* Home */
function Home (){
  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <Products />
      </div>
      <Promo />
      <Testimonials />  
      <Popular />    
    </>  
  )
}

etc....
```

I have a form in my GlobalNav component. When I submit the form, I would like to remove the existing components rendered between the GlobalNav and Footer components and render some new ones there instead.

The easiest solution would be to use

```
ReactDOM.render(<NewComponent />, document.getElementById(TARGET_DOM_NODE));
```

but this is now frowned upon in React 18.

How could I do this in a React18 friendly way?

Thanks, M

See above for details

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can accomplish this with some conditional rendering. When the form in your GlobalNav is submitted, it can either update a flag on the backend or the frontend state.

Then, just update whatever page you want to only render certain components based on that flag.

Generally speaking, you should never directly call `ReactDOM.render` except for your app root -- that is essentially circumventing all of the React-ness that makes React useful.

Here's an example of conditionally rendering some items in your Home component:

```
function Home (){
  
  // Set this based on API data or local state. Hard coded for demonstration.
  const formHasBeenSubmitted = true;

  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <Products />
      </div>
      <Promo />

      { !formHasBeenSubmitted && (
       <>
        <Testimonials />  
        <Popular />
       </>
      )} 

      { formHasBeenSubmitted && (
       <>
        <FormSubmittedComponent1 />  
        <FormSubmittedComponent2 />
       </>
      )} 
    </>  
  )
}
```

Depending on the complexity of your app, you can abstract this in a variety of ways. For example:

```
function Home (){
  
  // Set this based on API data or local state. Hard coded for demonstration.
  const formHasBeenSubmitted = true;

  const preFormSubmitElements = [<Testimonials />, <Popular />];
  const postFormSubmitElements = [<FormSubmittedComponent1 />, <FormSubmittedComponent2 />;

  const elementsToRender = formHasBeenSubmitted ? preFormSubmitElements : postFormSubmitElements;

  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <Products />
      </div>
      <Promo />

      {...elementsToRender}
    </>  
  )
}
```